# Usage of images in Primefaces <p:ring>

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, ring

I have a primafaces ring.I want to take images in xhtml codes.I have a papers library include images(paper1.jpg,paper2.jpg,..paper12.jpg). I don't want to use ringview.java.I added graphicimage tags between p:ring tags.But I don't display images.How can I do?

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:ring id="custom" value="#{ringView.papers}" var="paper">
         <p:graphicImage id="img" name="papers/#{paper}" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
    </p:ring>
</h:form>
```

RingView.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class RingView implements Serializable {

    private List<String> papers;
    private String selectedPaper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        papers = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            papers.add("paper" + i + ".jpg");
        }
    }     
    public List<String> getPapers() {
        return papers;
    }     
    public void setPapers(List<String> papers) {
        this.papers = papers;
    }     
    public String getSelectedPaper() {
        return selectedPaper;
    }
    public void setSelectedCar(String selectedPaper) {
        this.selectedPaper = selectedPaper;
    }
}
```

I tried something like:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:ring id="custom">
         <p:graphicImage id="img1" name="papers/paper1.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
     <p:graphicImage id="img2" name="papers/paper2.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
     <p:graphicImage id="img3" name="papers/paper3.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
</p:ring>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you have your images located, which folder? It should normally be located in `webapp/resources`, so in your case it would be probably something like `webapp/resources/papers/paper1.jpg`

Comment: My images are located in webapp/resources/papers/paper1.jpg

Comment: What do you see as an output?

Comment: I can not see anything

Comment: Do you have `<h:head></h:head>` on your page? If possible, please post some more code of your page.

Comment: Yes I have <h:head></h:head>